# How to Print the angle between joints in a Gazebo simulation.?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a model I made in gazebo, it is a linkage structure.it has 2 links which are joint by a revolute joint. I want one link to rotate around the other and I want to observe change angle positions of the joint.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279916/how-to-print-the-angle-between-joints-in-a-gazebo-simulation.-?/) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write a python script to print the real time angle between the joints .

http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher

---

Originally posted by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) with karma: 142 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0